# Laravel linking assets files to root of domain but not subfolder that the site is in

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a site that is `www.project.example.com/apps/myapp` and I have various javascript and css files linked like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('/css/myapp.css')}}"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/vendor.js')}}"></script>
```

But I keep getting a `404 not found` error because its looking for the files in `www.project.example.com/css` for example.. Its not even looking in the assets folder

How can I fix this without having to change the path for every css and javascript file?

Comment: It should be `asset('css/app.css')`.

Comment: I just changed it and it made no difference

Comment: Where do you expect it to look for your compiled asset files? It looks like you're confusing locations for "build" and "compiled" assets.

Comment: `asset()` points to the `public` folder of laravel.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it. had to set base href in index.php and use relative links

```
<base href="/apps/myapp/"

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css'"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myapp.css"/>
```